# Javascript get function arguments from an object?

Tags: javascript

So I'm wondering if/how I can use a value in a object as a arg in a function ex:

```
var mousePos = {
    chaos: (-950, 22)
}
console.log(mousePos.chaos) // chaos

mouse.Move(mousePos.chaos) // which would take two args, and then output Invalid number of arguments.
```

Comment: Your "chaos" property will have the value `22`, and the `-950` will be lost.

Comment: JS doesn't have tuples, so you need to use an array `[-950, 22]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for an array and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
var mousePos = {
    chaos: [-950, 22]
};
console.log(mousePos.chaos) // [-950, 22]

mouse.move(...mousePos.chaos) // equivalent to `mouse.move(-950, 22)`
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can if you use an array and `Function.prototype.apply`

```
var mousePos = {
  chaos: [-950, 22]
}

mouse.Move.apply(mouse, mousePos.chaos)
```

If you are fancy and are using Node or Babel, you can also use spread syntax:

```
mose.Move(...mousePos.chaos)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a single object with two value (x,y) for mouse position.
so manage your object like key/value base array.

```
var mousePos = { chaos: {x : -950, y:22} };
mouse.move(mousePos.chaos.x,mousePos.chaos.y) // equivalent to 
mouse.move(-950,22)
```